# How to make apache to read .htaccess files while do proxy to multiple virutual hosts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

I m using `apache 2.4` and `tomcat 8` on `Ubuntu 14` server. As I m using same server for both 'dev' and 'test', so im using virtual host in apache that check from request if comming and redirect to differnt directory of tomcat where related code resides. Now I have a requirement to use .htaccess file to prerender our site for SEO purpose.

As .htaccess file gets ignore by tomcat so in apache, for each virtual host, I want apache to consider related .htaccess file and then redirect request to related virtual host.

Is it possible??

Here are my both apache virtual host configuration files

Test .htaccess file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName test.myapp.com
ServerAlias www.test.myapp.com
DocumentRoot /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/test.MyApp.com/ROOT

ProxyPass / http://test.myapp.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://test.myapp.com:8080/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/test.MyApp.com/ROOT">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Dev .htaccess file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName dev.myapp.com
DocumentRoot /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/dev.MyApp.com/ROOT

ProxyPass / http://dev.myapp.com:8080/

ProxyPassReverse / http://dev.myapp.com:8080/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.14/dev.MyApp.com/ROOT">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In apache2.conf file, I also change to this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: any solution for this?